# Grouping values together

Tags: r, arrays

I am trying to group my data in such a way that the first value of each dataset, followed by the second value of each dataset, and then the third value of each dataset. Here is what I have done, and what each dataset looks like:

```
#datasets created
newmax <- sapply(unstack(subset), function(r){max(values(r))})
newmax1 <- sapply(unstack(subset5), function(r){max(values(r))})
newmax2 <- sapply(unstack(subset18), function(r){max(values(r))})

> newmax
[1] 285.9906 287.6668 276.2251 247.1718 254.9781 308.1921 234.6858 235.7213 242.0865 247.1022 
233.6528 243.9972 297.6855
[14] 264.3488 251.2206 249.4745 242.8481 241.2680 347.7225 241.0539 359.7334 256.2414 343.5733 
270.5300 237.6458 260.9076
[27] 281.6629 273.9240 237.9238 237.8657 274.8282 254.7619 274.5488 240.1335 288.5369 263.7763 
256.8988 237.8154 335.7295
[40] 251.1009 268.0298 284.0815 335.7390 260.6265 261.9585 245.4095 317.5088 326.1608 301.0854 
256.6393 261.7769 248.8044
[53] 316.8620 285.2788 291.7393 282.7814 295.2238 263.5885 293.1581 323.0423 275.8465 321.7197 
267.7597 260.1087 300.4011
[66] 289.7009 312.8771 247.2548 310.7060 293.6764 294.6003 301.9609 274.3764 324.2272 326.5802 
312.4825 306.0726 271.3173
[79] 292.4768 270.7873 287.0801 363.9818 256.2259 282.1166 305.7313 276.7374 356.4052 296.8313 
355.2177 360.6911

> newmax1
[1] 159.0246 133.6294 153.0331 160.4190 148.2776 142.6571 172.3195 157.7454 148.3942 165.9219  
139.6812 140.4338 161.9404
[14] 136.1558 222.1469 160.5796 146.9243 146.8993 138.4256 181.2822 180.0468 136.2687 149.4805 
169.0774 156.5708 197.8407
[27] 191.2747 171.9067 302.4844 161.1594 166.2600 150.5847 171.2477 153.5008 176.8167 164.1645 
202.1044 185.5567 159.5147
[40] 188.2911 157.7030 159.3245 168.7951 145.3923 184.0441 169.1975 152.4814 157.8601 218.1362 
181.0313 241.6280 145.9474
[53] 181.1191 197.6868 160.4712 166.6491 182.9139 202.4592 164.4607 192.3751 216.7510 155.9616 
223.6624 170.2424 192.1529
[66] 166.4860 162.0195 231.3395 178.0869 212.7882 172.4338 174.4920 196.2973 195.0461 232.1316 
160.4764 235.2968 248.9072
[79] 164.1591 193.9029 173.5751 233.6983 160.4132 178.4975 238.9297 184.6619 202.9835 244.6498   
225.4075 180.8024


> newmax2
[1] 240.5591 200.7394 215.9244 211.9053 194.3641 243.4610 185.3560 224.9627 191.5551 202.0553 
219.7212 182.8306 218.4132
[14] 226.3639 234.4197 216.8123 225.2460 192.8765 257.7413 197.9228 213.0739 271.9188 192.6500 
195.1350 194.0970 203.7642
[27] 179.7267 216.7133 199.1632 223.2381 248.6822 211.2326 241.4532 197.2935 194.6268 189.2713 
198.8254 217.6894 227.3989
[40] 218.0017 198.4878 271.2049 225.8836 195.0280 235.8415 269.6207 177.6220 218.8525 238.0074 
231.2968 206.1418 251.5883
[53] 195.4047 176.4463 265.4490 274.9973 262.3909 214.1287 348.5859 272.7213 230.3467 208.9446 
247.6072 246.7016 225.6779
[66] 213.9412 279.3386 229.7833 270.4096 235.7482 211.5287 235.5385 200.0058 221.8117 210.8134   
252.3336 214.9943 262.2128
[79] 217.4706 211.3952 216.3089 227.9274 282.2023 232.6686 239.9312 209.6954 238.7950 284.0325 
233.5386 232.6486
```

To isolated the first, second and third values, I tried this:

```
combined <- cbind(newmax[1],newmax1[1], newmax2[1], newmax[2], newmax1[2], newmax2[2], 
newmax[3], newmax1[3], newmax2[3])

> combined

     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]
[1,] 285.9906 159.0246 240.5591 287.6668 133.6294 200.7394 276.2251 153.0331 215.9244
```

That's exactly what I wanted (i.e. all the first values, then the second values and third values lined up). However, I want the data arranged like in the original datasets (i.e. newmax, newmax1, newmax2)  - using "cbind" seemingly creates columns? Also, would there be a faster way to arrange the values the same way, or is what I have done the only way?

Thank you, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give something like 
`sapply(x,``[` `, c(1,2,3))`
which will apply indexing to your object x a shot;
Or something like

`lapply(X = x, FUN = subset, select=c(1,2,3))`

in case of columns, not sure judging from your data what exactly fits you.
PS: `rbind` will do row binding just like `cbind` does column binding

Comment: Thank you so much for this response! 

I tried this, as well: combined <- c(newmax[1],newmax1[1], newmax2[1], newmax[2],newmax1[2], newmax2[2], newmax[3],newmax1[3], newmax2[3] This worked perfectly and gives precisely what I want, but I was wondering if there is a faster or more condensed way to do the same thing? Thanks, again

Comment: accepting the answer is common practice on SO; 
more condensed than 1 line - not sure about that

Comment: GWD - I used just the "c" function to merge my data, since this creates no columns (just standard rows). However, while what I have newly done (see my above comment) works fine, would it be possible to arrange my data the same way, but faster, as I did with the "c" function in my above comment? For example, arranging all of the first values to appear first, then all of the second values to follow, and then all of the third values to follow that? Thanks, again

Comment: hmm - not really sure, but sounds a bit like u just want this `df <- data.frame(ColA=newmax, ColB=newmax1, ColC=newmax2)` if that is not your expected order than transpose it? `t(df)`

Comment: That actually works fine! Thank you for this suggestion!